# copying vector of maps data into a map of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, maps

Sorry for posting the same problem again, but I used the suggested solutions, and it partially worked...
So I want to clarify the problem:

So:

I defined a vector of maps, like this:

```
typedef vector<map<string,unsigned int> > myvec;
```

And a map of vectors (i called it index) like this:

```
typedef map<string,vector<unsigned int> > index;
```

Then I did the following:

In my class, called myCoogle, i declared `myvec maps_vec;`

and I filled it with maps...

In each map there's a word (string) and a number (unsinged int).

So far so good.

I declared also `index the_index;`

Now I want to copy all the different words from the_vec to the_index.

The words will be the strings...

And for each vector i will be adding the numbers stored in the vector of maps.

For example:

the_vec has 3 maps.

> the 1st has: chicken,1 **|** person,1 **|** elevator,5 **|** is,2 **|** ...
>
> the 2nd has: person,2 **|** icecream,3 **|** is,3 **|** ...
>
> the 3rd has: elevator,1 **|** bear,1 **|** is,4 **|** chicken,3 **|** ...

So the_index should look like this:

*word,[vector of ints]*

> chicken[1,0,3]
>
> person,[1,2,0]
>
> elevator[5,0,1]
>
> is[2,3,4]
>
> icecream[0,3,0]
>
> bear[0,0,1]

OK here's my function:

```
void Coogle::make_index()
{
    //SCAN THE FIRST MAP
    myvec::iterator myvec_iter;
    map<string,unsigned int>::iterator map_iter;
    index::iterator idx_iter = the_index.begin();
    for(map_iter=maps_vec[0].begin(); map_iter!=maps_vec[0].end(); ++map_iter)
    {
        the_index[map_iter->first].push_back(map_iter->second);
    }


    //SCAN THE OTHER MAPS
    myvec_iter=maps_vec.begin();
    myvec_iter++;
    int i=0; //FILE #
    while(myvec_iter!=maps_vec.end())
    {
        i++;
        for(map_iter=maps_vec[i].begin(); map_iter!=maps_vec[i].end(); ++map_iter)
        {
            string word=map_iter->first;
            cout << "DEALING WITH WORD \"" << word << "\"" << endl;
            index::iterator location;
            location=the_index.find(word);
            if(location!=the_index.end()) //if word found in the index
            {
                cout << "WORD EXISTS!" << endl;
                location->second[i]=map_iter->second;
            }
            else //if not found
            {
                cout << "WORD DOES NOT EXIST! NEW WORD." << endl;
                the_index[word].push_back(map_iter->second);
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
        ++myvec_iter;
    }
}
```

clarification: FILE# is the maps number... I'm working with files (*.txt files).

Alright so after I scanned the first map, I tried to print the_index and all was fine.
But I get this when trying to print after scanning also the other maps:

[image: the bug]

'Build Successfully' though.

And this window pops up when I run the program.

So I believe something is wrong with my 2nd 'for' loop.

Anyone can help please?

Very sorry for the very long post...

Thank you very much !!!

**edit:
If I don't try to print the_index, the program compiles and runs just fine.
But that's not enough ofcourse.
But my print function is just alright... here:**

```
void Coogle::print_index() const
{
    index::const_iterator iter;
    for(iter=the_index.begin();iter!=the_index.end();++iter)
    {
        cout << "Word: " << iter->first << endl;
        //cout << "Files number is: " << files_number << endl; //prints: 3
        for(int i=0; i<files_number;i++)
            cout << "file #" << i+1 << ": " << iter->second[i] << " , " << endl;
    }
}
```

**edit:**

Here's a screen shot of printing only 1 map vs printing 3 maps:

[image: 1 map vs 3]

Comment: Please provide the declaration of your variables. Also, what is line 916?

Comment: Standard algorithms could really improve readability of your code, IMO.

Comment: Which variables? the_vec was corrected. it's just maps_vec.

Comment: Plus. there is no line 916. I don't know where is that coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Ok hopefully I finally understand what you're trying to do.

```
typdef myvec::iter vmiter_t;
typdef map<string,unsigned int>::iter miter_t;
typdef set<string>::iter siter_t;

set<string> words;

for(vmiter_t vmiter=maps_vec.begin(); vmiter != maps_vec.end(); ++vmiter)
{
    for(miter_t miter = vmiter->begin(); miter != vmiter->.end(); ++miter)
    {
        words.insert(miter->first);
    }
}

for (siter_t iter=words.begin(); iter!=words.end(); ++iter){
    const string& word = *iter;
    for(vmiter_t vmiter=maps_vec.begin(); vmiter != maps_vec.end(); ++vmiter)
    {
        map<string,unsigned int>& temp = *vmiter;
        the_index[word].push_back(temp[word]);
    }
}
```

It's hard to tell since you didn't provide the declaration of your variables (and some of them seem to be misnamed), but I think the problem is the line `location->second[i]=map_iter->second;`. You are trying to access index i in the vector, but your vector isn't actually that long.

Edit: Now that I can tell what you're actually trying to do, you're massively overcomplicating things. You don't need a seperate loop for the other elements at all.

Comment: Which variables are you talking about? Is it the_vec and maps_vec? Sorry there is only maps_vec. I just corrected that. And by location->second[i] I'm trying to access the vector in place i. (the vector which is in the map that is). And my vector's length is 3.

Comment: Ok I provided an example of how to do things. Your second loop appears to be completely wrong.

Comment: I got the same result with  your function... Check it out at the edit.

Comment: @Adam, sorry I didn't understand what you were trying to do before. Try my new solution. (Remember to `#include <set>`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a C++11 answer:

```
myvec v = /* ... */;

index q;

for (auto const & m : v)
    for (auto const & p : m)
        q[p->first].emplace_back(p->second);
```

It's the same as @Antimony's solution, just a bit easier on the eye.